# What is the equivalent of Oracle's REF CURSOR in Postgresql when using JDBC?

Tags: java, oracle, postgresql, jdbc, plsql

**In Oracle I can declare a reference cursor...**

```
TYPE t_spool IS REF CURSOR RETURN spool%ROWTYPE;
```

**...and use it to pass a cursor as the return value...**

```
FUNCTION end_spool
    RETURN t_spool
    AS
    v_spool t_spool;
    BEGIN
        COMMIT;
        OPEN v_spool FOR
            SELECT
                *
            FROM
                spool
            WHERE
                key = g_spool_key
            ORDER BY
                seq;
        RETURN v_spool;
    END end_spool;
```

**...and then capture it as a result set using JDBC...**

```
private Connection conn;
private CallableStatement stmt;
private OracleResultSet rset;
[...clip...]
stmt = conn.prepareCall("{ ? = call " + call + "}");
stmt.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.CURSOR);
stmt.execute();
rset = (OracleResultSet)stmt.getObject(1);
```

**What is the equivalent in Postgresql?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this will help: http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/83/callproc.html#callproc-resultset-setof

I haven't really messed with that before :P